# Syntastic java external library support

Tags: java, vim, syntastic

I'm trying to program a game using lwjgl library and I'm using vim as my editor. I would like to have syntax cheking so I use syntastic.

The [javac checker page](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/Java%3A---javac) explains how to add the classpath to the javac checker using SyntasticJavacEditClasspath command.

My problem is that I put there the path to lwjgl.jar and lwjgl_utils.jar and it's still founding a lot of missing library errors.

I put this on the opened buffer:

```
/home/ionthas/development/java/Jump2Box/lib/jars/lwjgl.jar
```

I think I'm inserting the classpath in the wrong way.

Here is one of the 17 errors that show up: (The code runs perfectly)

```
src/com/ionsoft/engine/Engine.java|1 col 17 error| 
package org.lwjgl does not exist import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
```

Here it is my configuration in .vimrc

```
18 " Syntastic                    
19 highlight SyntasticErrorSign guifg=white guibg=red          
20 highlight SyntasticErrorLine guibg=red                              
21 let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1                                    
22 let g:syntastic_enable_signs = 0                                
23 let g:syntastic_enable_ballons = 0                  
24 let g:syntastic_quiet_warnings = 1
25 let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
26 let g:syntastic_java_checkers = ['checkstyle', 'javac'] 
27 let g:syntastic_stl_format = '[%E{Err: %fe #%e}%B{, }%W{Warn: %fw #%w}]'                                     
28 let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'active',
29                         \ 'active_filetypes': ['ruby', 'java'],
30                         \ 'passive_filetypes': [''] }
31 let g:syntastic_java_javac_classpath = '~/home/ionthas/development/java/Jump2Box/lib/jars/lwjgl.jar'
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I solved the problem using the relative path

    ./lib/jars/lwjgl.jar

insted of the absolute path

    /home/ionthas/development/java/Jump2Box/lib/jars/lwjgl.jar

Comment: Please add that as an answer (and accept it) to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tilde `~` is your home directory. In your case, probably `/home/ionthas/`.
 So your classpath:

```
~/home/ionthas/development/java/Jump2Box/lib/jars/lwjgl.jar
```

Would actually expand to:

```
/home/ionthas/home/ionthas/development/java/Jump2Box/lib/jars/lwjgl.jar
```

An extra home directory, hence the error.
Taking out the tilde `~` would probably do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

If you use gradle to manage your project you can use the following plugin to automatically manage you classpath. Every time you add/update dependencies it will update a local class path file.

https://github.com/Scuilion/gradle-syntastic-plugin

Comment: Very nice! This works. Great work! Took me a while to figure out that I had to run `gradle syntastic` to actually generate the file. The usage instructions could be a tiny bit clearer for Gradle newbies like me.

Comment: @UTF_or_Death, it will also automatically build the syntastic file when you call `gradle build`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the relative path

```
./lib/jars/lwjgl.jar
```

insted of the absolute path

```
/home/ionthas/development/java/Jump2Box/lib/jars/lwjgl.jar
```